# Finding a NSString inside a NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I'm trying to find a NSString that is the same as an object inside an NSArray

So i have this so far

```
SPButton *currentBalloon = (SPButton *)[event target];

NSUInteger x =[letterArray indexOfObject:currentLetter];
NSUInteger y =[letterArray indexOfObject:currentBalloon.info];
if (y == x) {
    // do the following code
    NSLog(@"Equal!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not Equal!");

}
```

I keep crashing on the indexOfObject line. Anybody god any ideas?

Comment: Can we get a little more context? As it is, your code may be wrong depending on what you are trying to do. For example, if both currentLetter and currentBalloon.info aren't in NSArray, your code will say they are equal, when they are not.

Comment: POST THE CRASH INFO FROM THE CONSOLE

Comment: What kind of object is currentLetter, or indeed, is it an object at all? That would crash it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're going about this in a very long winded way, getting the index of a letter in an array (presumably alphabetically ordered) then comparing indexes. Why not just compare the two letters?

```
if ([currentLetter isEqualToString:currentBalloon.info]) ...
```

Comment: The issue wasn't with the if but i forgot to retain the currentLetter String so after i did that i just used the isEqualToString: and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator compares object pointers. Use `[y isEqualToString:x]` if you want to compare values.

Comment: Oh riiiight. Shame on me for reading it too quickly. What's the problem then?

Comment: It keeps crashing whenever it runs, it crashes on indexofobjects

Comment: Well then perhaps you'd like to share the crash info with us. Also make sure you're not using `indexOfObects` (plural), which doesn't exist. I presume that was just a typo in your above comment as the code you posted uses `indexOfObject`